# Responsive images for lazyload and isotope

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design, jquery-isotope, jquery-lazyload

How can I make images responsive for lazyload coupled with isotope jquery plugins? So far I have the following code :

```
<div class="thumbnail item">
    <a href="image.jpg" class="fbgroup" rel="fbgroup">
        <img class="lazy" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" data-original="thumb_image.jpg" height="auto" width="auto" style="height:300px; width:450px;" />
        <noscript><img src="image.jpg" height="auto" width="auto" style="width:450px; height:300px" /></noscript>
    </a>
</div>
```

Lazyload works like this and so does masonry in isotope, but when I resize the browser to something thinner than the width of the image it breaks out of the pages content container and will not shrink responsively. What makes it difficult is lazyload seems to want the real width and height of the image in the style section of the img tag.

Comment: lazy load wants the width and height only before the real image loads so that it can put in a filler (i.e. `dot.gif`). You can not put them in and the filler wont show properly, but it might not matter. You don't want to set the `src` on lazyload you want to use `data-original` and let the script set the `src`.

Comment: Also if you are putting in the whole image in `base64` into the `dom`, the benefits of lazyload are questionable (one less request, but a heavier initial load).

Comment: @Victory ok so I will use a blank gif for the source instead of the blank png base 64 I am using above. I definitely need some sort of source for the image otherwise it breaks isotope masonry. What you say is a great tip but it doesn't help me with the problem at hand.